# How can I control which monitors a program can see in Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

How can I control which monitors a program can see in Microsoft Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate?

For example, one can control which GPUs a program has access to by using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` (assuming CUDA is being used):

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,1" python myprogram.py
```

My use case: a program I use to open MRI images automatically use all my monitors, which I don't want.

Comment: You could at least provide the version of Windows ...

Comment: @DavidPostill added